# JQuery click check box to display specific field from div

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a dropdown to show values in 3 different Checkboxes using Jquery. But when I clicked on the checkbox no input field display?

```js
$('#response').click(function() {
  if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
    $("#displayrow").show();
  } else {
    $("#displayrow").hide();
  }
});

/*
     function Payoutmethods(countryid){
            $.ajax({
            url: "abc.php",
            type: "post",
            data: {cid:cid},
            success: function (methods){
            $('#displayresponse').html(methods);
            }            
                }); 
*/
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="control-group">

  <div class="controls" id="displayresponse">
    <input type="checkbox" name="response" id="response" value="">
  </div>
</div>
<div id="displayrow" style="display: none;">
  <div class="control-group">
    <div class="controls">
      <input type="text" id="displayrow" name="displayrow" />
      <input type="text" name="displayrow" id="displayrow" />
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be working correctly. I have tested it below and when the checkbox is clicked the inputs show and hide. You could be having a problem with your ajax that is stopping the rest of your code from working.

Or, if you need this to work for items that are not in the DOM then you should run the click function targeting something outside of the div like the body and then using the jquery "on" function.

```js
/* //////////////SHOW AND HIDE INPUT FIELDS//// */

/*
$('#response').click(function() {
  if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
    $("#displayrow").show();
  } else {
    $("#displayrow").hide();
  }
});

*/

// If you need this to work for items that are not in the DOM then you should run the click function like this. 

$('body').on("click", "#response",function() {
  if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
    $("#displayrow").show();
  } else {
    $("#displayrow").hide();
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="control-group">
  <!-- // displayresponse id -- get value(Student , Teacher. Subject and each values has specific input fields) from abc page and display here in div -->
  <div class="controls" id="displayresponse">
    CLICK ME --> <input type="checkbox" name="response" id="response" value="">
  </div>
</div>
<div id="displayrow" style="display: none;">
  <div class="control-group">
    <div class="controls">
      <input type="text" id="displayrow" name="displayrow" value="test1" />
      <input type="text" id="displayrow" name="displayrow" value="test2"/>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This won't work since you can only have on element with a specific ID. So `#response` will only target one element. Better to use clases here.

Comment: i have 3 checkboxed with different values when i click on first check it show 

first show --Fname , lname input
2nd show --> email , pass 
3rd show -- > phone or any input field

Answer (score 0):

You need to place your code within `$(function() {...})` to be excuted only once [document is loaded](https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/):

```
$(function() {

  $('#response').change(function(){
    if( $(this).is(':checked')) 
    {
      $("#displayrow").show();
    } else {
      $("#displayrow").hide();
    }
  });
  
});
```

```js
$(function() {

  $('#response').change(function(){
    if( $(this).is(':checked')) 
    {
      $("#displayrow").show();
    } else {
      $("#displayrow").hide();
    }
  });
  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="control-group">

<div class="controls" id="displayresponse">
<input type="checkbox" name="response" id="response" value="">
</div></div>
    <div id="displayrow" style="display: none;">
    <div class="control-group"><div class="controls">
        <input type="text" id="displayrow" name="displayrow" / >
        <input type="text" name="displayrow" id="displayrow" />      
</div></div></div>
```

Comment: its already working but am fetching ID value in  checkbox  from DB and when I check the box it will show input fields accordingly